# node-quickbooks vs intuit-oauth

Tags: node.js, api, integration, quickbooks-online

I am doing research on quickbooks online integration using node and angular 8.

The official intuit developer site provides two node packages. 
one is official from intuit and one is from community.

I have glanced through both of them.
the official package is fairly universal. It essentially is just a API client to send a request to remote server and the payload is basic json format.

the community package seems a bit more specific but the documentation seems a bit confusing.

Which one would you choose to do the work and why?
I would love to hear your input.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intuit provided library (intuit-oauth) is specifically for authenticating and getting the OAuth token you need to communicate with the Quickbooks API, the other library (node-quickbooks) is for making the actual calls against the API endpoints.

You will need both libraries, unless you are handling authentication in a different way.

Comment: Hi. So when i tried using node-quickbooks after authenticating from intuit-oauth its not working. intuit-oauth require clientId and clientsecret while node-quickbooks consumerId and secret which from what i've learned is from oauth1 not oauth2 (oauth2 uses clientId and secret) which intuit-oauth is using by default.

Is there any way to connect to quickbooks using node-quickbooks after authenticating using oauth2?

Comment: Do you have any example code for using both libraries to make calls to the api?  I have a valid token generated however it seems to be expired but I can't seem to access the error via code to be able to catch it and refresh the token.  Any suggestions on how I catch the expired token error generated when making a call via node-quickbooks and then refreshing the token?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw for whoever finds this useful:

I forked intuit-oauth, added typescript and fixed vulnerabilities that have been fixed in the PRs of their repo for years and never updated here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/intuit-oauth-ts

Additionally I forked node-quickbooks, updated the api to return promises rather than relying on callbacks, resolved the discovery URLs automatically, changed the format of response objects to be more sensible, and added (unfortunately only some) of the typescript definitions for it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qbo. I don't have enough time to add the definitions for all of the files (largey because the included ones should be completely exhaustive for every property in the QBO api, which is timeconsuming to define). If someone would like to contribute by adding more of the typescript definitions or adding all of them, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I am interested in any example angular app using intuit-oauth

Trying to work it out but getting issues since there is no document for typescript.

Comment: That fits to what i found so far. In the same boat.